# Keras create dataset from CSV without TensorFlow

Tags: python, keras, plaidml

On every question and tutorial I have found, tf.data.Dataset is used for CSV files, but I am not using tensorflow, I am using PlaidML because my AMD GPU is not supported in ROCm. I have tried using the same code by doing

```py
os.environ["KERAS_BACKEND"] = "plaidml.keras.backend"
from tensorflow import keras
```

but that still does not use the plaidml backend. How do I load this dataset: https://www.kaggle.com/keplersmachines/kepler-labelled-time-series-data into keras without tensorflow? Thank you. I check if the plaidml backend is used by looking at the output. If it says "Using plaidml.keras.backend backend", then it is using plaidml. Also, only plaidml recognizes my GPU, so tensorflow will use my CPU.

Comment: Im curious how you check if something is using the plaidml backend. Could you add that to your question?

Comment: I would check the whether the output says Using plaidml.keras.backend backend, and if the CPU is used. If it is using GPU, and not as much CPU then it is using PlaidML.